# show loading on jquery refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this JQuery code that loads a php file into a div every X Seconds

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); // This part addresses an IE bug. without it, IE will only load the first number and will never refresh
setInterval(function() {
$('.container').load('dashboard.php');
}, 10000); // the "3000" here refers to the time to refresh the div. it is in milliseconds.
});
// ]]></script>

<div class="container"><h3>Loading Dashboard...</h3></div>
```

when the loading starts it shows the `Loading Dashboard` text but then every X seconds it just refreshes the content in the background. how can i show some sort of loading image each time it refreshes?

Comment: Use a loading indicator as background of the container, then hide it in the `load` callback.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

1) at the very top of your setInterval function, before you execute the load, set the background of that container class to be a loading image (or however you want to display it).

2) use the callback function of .load (https://api.jquery.com/load/) to remove that loading image when the load has completed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fiddle illustrating the direction you should take...

http://jsfiddle.net/j5sZc/

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <h3 class="loader">Loading Dashboard...</h3>
    <div class="container"></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); // This part addresses an IE bug. without it, IE will only load the first number and will never refresh

    var $loader = $(".loader"), // cache references to loader and container
        $container = $(".container");

    setInterval(function() {
        $loader.show(); // show loader when request is initialized
        $container.empty().load('dashboard.php', function(){
            $loader.hide(); // hide loader once new content is loaded
        });
    }, 10000); // the "3000" here refers to the time to refresh the div. it is in milliseconds.
});
```